# showing comments on a separate tab

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is it possible to put comments on a separate tab when viewing the node?how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create a page view that shows the comments and set the menu path to be a Local Task of the node

in the menu path you would put something like `node/%/comments`

Answer (score 2):

I use [Talk](http://drupal.org/project/talk) module.i thing is better!

Comment: totally forgot about that one. Yeah easier than even a view.

Answer (score 1):

There has been [some discussion](http://drupal.org/node/566688) in the [Quick Tabs module](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) issue queue about adding the ability to put comments on a separate tab. Apparently the module doesn't yet support it, but someone posted a [small modification](http://drupal.org/node/507446#comment-1766496) (ie, hack) to the module that supposedly gets it working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use QUICKTAB module.It will be good for putting comments on the web page.
You can create 3 to 4 tabs and there is a list of options for the appearance of the tab.In order to link the comments first you have to create a block for each comments  and assign the block to this tab.